# Unable to use reactjs ldap-authentication module, Error: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, npm, ldap

I am developing one web application. I am using Django in the backend and reactjs in the frontend. I want to implement LDAP authentication with GroupWise permission.

1. I am unable to find out good example or way to do this. Where should I implement LDAP - Djnago or reactjs??
2. If I use node module that is **ldap-authentication**. Source code is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldap-authentication
   I am getting below error:

Error: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839

below are the param I am providing in code:

```
let options = {
        ldapOpts: {
          url: CONFIG.ldap.url,
        },
        // note in this example it only use the user to directly
        // bind to the LDAP server. You can also use an admin
        // here. See the document of ldap-authentication.
        userDn: `uid=${req.body.username},${ldapBaseDn}`,
        userPassword: req.body.password,
        userSearchBase: ldapBaseDn,
        usernameAttribute: 'UID',
        username: req.body.username,
        adminPassword: CONFIG.ldap.password,
        adminDn: 'cn=CONFIG.ldap.name,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,ou=Service Accounts,ou=xxx,ou=Common',
        verifyUserExists : true
      }
```

Note: My LDAP server is not public and in reactjs ldap-authentication example they have used public ldap server. I am using https://github.com/shaozi/passport-ldap-example example for reactjs ldap implementation.

Thank you.